What is the longest known series of consecutive pawn promotions ever played in a FIDE rated game?
What is the longest known series of consecutive pawn promotions (to any piece) ever played in a FIDE rated game?

There is no database of ALL rated games, so this question can't be answered.

@IanRingrose Okay, then all games that can be found...but anyways this question and this question got an answer...
